# I want to added range element to change css image filter-with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter, range

This is code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .saturate {-webkit-filter: saturate(3);}
        </style>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="img/brz.jpg" class="warning" id = "great">
        <br> </br>
        <input id="" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="30"/>
        <button type="button"  onclick ="Saturate()">Saturate</button>
        <script>
            var Saturate = function() {
                document.getElementById("great").className = "";
                document.getElementById("great").classList.add("saturate");
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is link http://codepen.io/narenb93/pen/oxYByX

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your end goal from the title, what I would do is have the `img` overlay another element (like a `div`), and have the `img`'s `src` be the `background-image` of the element.

Then tie a javascript event handler to the range input that toggles the opacity of the `img` against the original (which is a `background-image`), which should produce the desired effect.

Here's a demo - http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/oBXWGV

Comment: range element that can control the behavior filter but using background

Comment: thanks :). range element that can control the behavior of filters but not by using background image as a overlap 
i need the control i mean range element that can control the behavior of filters
example:http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KwmeJZ